# qmake missing object file

Tags: qt, compilation, qmake

Alright... So I am very new to Qt. I just installed it on my Ubuntu distribution.
I created a new test application to see if it worked with the following file (helloworld.cpp) in my ../helloworld/ directory:

```
/*  helloworld.cpp */
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and I ran `qmake -project` in order to generate the helloworld.pro file.
Next I ran `qmake` in order to genereate the Makefile
Next I ran `make` in order to compile and got the following output/error:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG 
-DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. 
-I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 
-I. -I. -o helloworld.o helloworld.cpp
helloworld.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [helloworld.o] Error 1
```

meaning the helloworld.o file is missing... How do I fix this? I tried adding `QT += webkit` as another discussion said... and that didn't work either.

Any code monkeys out there have any ideas how to fix this??? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QApplication` should be inside `/usr/include/qt4/QtGui`, provided you have installed the `libqt4-dev` package.
If that package is not installed, that's the reason of the error: just install it:

`sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel... You saved me tons of time and headache!

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro file, add the below line

```
 QT += core widgets gui
```

Don't forget to invoke `qmake` again in command line so that `qmake` recreates `Makefile`.  This should fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The actual error is a missing header file (QApplication).  That caused your code (helloworld.cpp) not to compile generating a secondary error

```
make: *** [helloworld.o] Error 1
```

Thus, the solution is to make sure QApplication can be found.  That usually is handled by the `Qt +=` statement in your .pro file.

`Qt += webkit` tells QMake that you are wanting to make a webkit (web browser) application.  That should not be needed in this case.

What you are trying to build is a GUI application, so you need to make sure your .pro file specifies that.  That can be done by specifying `Qt += gui`.

More over, I would suggest that you have `Qt += gui core` at the top of your file.  This tells QMake that you are using both the core and gui components of Qt.